# .Bat file help - deleting duplicate lines and using variables

Tags: batch-file, duplicates, rename

I have a file that I need to delete the duplicate lines. The file input name has a date and I need to keep that file and create a new file with a variable on the end...Perhaps the current date. This is what i have without variables:

```
@ECHO ON

SET InputFile=C:\FM\FM_ADT_20221003.txt
::SET InputFile=%~1
SET OutputFile=C:\FM\FM_ADT_20221003(current date).txt

SET PSScript=%Temp%\~tmpRemoveDupe.ps1
IF EXIST "%PSScript%" DEL /Q /F "%PSScript%"
ECHO Get-Content "%InputFile%" ^| Sort-Object ^| Get-Unique ^> "%OutputFile%">>"%PSScript%"

SET PowerShellDir=C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
CD /D "%PowerShellDir%"
Powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PSScript%'"

GOTO EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your question as you want to get the current date inside the output file, and you don't need to create another .ps1 file to execute it, instead, you can simply exceute as powershell command :

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Remove Duplicate Lines
Call:GetFileNameWithDateTime stamp
SET InputFile="%~1"
If [%InputFile%] EQU [""] exit /b 1
SET OutputFile=%~dpn1(%stamp%).txt
::echo/ "%OutputFile%" & pause
Powershell -C "Get-Content '%InputFile%' | Sort-Object | Get-Unique >'%OutputFile%'"
If Exist "%OutputFile%" Start "" "%OutputFile%"
GOTO EOF
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetFileNameWithDateTime <stamp>
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set "MyDate=%%x"
set "%1=%MyDate:~0,4%%MyDate:~4,2%%MyDate:~6,2%"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```